How to display all columns of an array at once?
I am working with Matlab 2024a on MS Windows. I am working in the Matlab GUI.
I have an array which has 61 rows and 15 columns, named X_foo. If I just say
>> X_foo

at the command prompt, it is displayed with columns 1 through 14, all rows, and then column 15, all rows.
Of course, the number of columns which are displayed is a function of the width of the window. The essential point is that Matlab breaks up the array into blocks of columns, such that each block fits within the display line length, and then displays the array block by block.
How can I tell Matlab not to break up the array into column blocks, and just display all columns, whatever the width? I looked at Preferences / Command Window, and I see both "Wrap lines" and "Set matrix display to eighty columns" are both disabled. What else can I try? Is there any way to tell Matlab the line length for the command window? I looked, but did not find such a variable.

You can use explicit fprintf statements to write data to the terminal in any way you want, I guess.

Robert: the solution in my answer of making the window much wider than the screen works on my Mac, but I just tried it on a Windows computer, and you are correct that it doesn't work, so I deleted my answer.

As an alternative solution, would viewing the stored array through the "Workspace" tab in the MATLAB GUI be helpful? If X_foo is a variable used in the terminal, then it should show up in the GUI's Workspace tab, which you can interact with. Double clicking it should bring up a spreadsheet-like view of the entire contents of the variable.

Thanks, using the variable viewer in the Workspace is the best solution.
